# Why isn't the Sad Clown's torso in Stud.io?

Tags: minifigures, software, bricklink-studio

I was working on designing a clown minifig and I found the [973pb1398c01 Torso 3 Black Pom Poms Pattern / White Arms / Black Hands](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973pb1398c01&idColor=1#T=C&C=1) that seemed perfect for it, but it turns out that it isn't in Stud.io.

[image: 973pb1398c01]

So, am I using the wrong tool for designing minifigs? Is there an easy way to get new parts like this into Stud.io? Is there an explanation for which parts are available?

Comment: Since Stud.io part libary is based on LDraw project's results (basically, a community effort) I suspect nobody did produce a print for this torso.

Comment: I figured since it was done by bricklink that it would be more complete.  I will try the Part Designer as PhilB suggests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stud.io only has a small selection of printed parts, but there is hope. Stud.io’s Part Designer tool can help you with your clown torso. Here’s how:

1. Using a paint tool (like Windows’ Paint3D), save only the center bit of the torso to a PNG file, using the above torso image as your master.
2. Open up Part Designer and choose the option to modify a part. Search for the torso part (Part Designer does not care about the color).
3. Once the torso part is loaded, choose to add a decoration using the proper option in the left side menu (bottom-most option in my version).
4. Now open up your PNG file and position it over the torso so that the pompoms line up with the middle of the torso.
5. Save your part, import it back into Stud.io, go to your Custom part library (selector on the top left side of your screen above the Parts Library) and use the torso as you want.

All these steps shouldn’t take more than a few minutes. Good luck!

Comment: Just wanted to note that there are templates (or size information?) for the correct images size for the individual body parts somewhere in the Stud.io docs. Have used this approach several times successfully. May take a few tries to get it right the first time (especially for head parts/faces).

Comment: I was surprised that it was an independent download.  I was able to get a torso that looks right enough for now.  Thanks for the help.